# volume absorption range

Tags: shader-nodes

How can I increase the difference between the volume absorption in thinner areas of an object compared to thicker areas? If I increase density, both thicker and thinner parts are affected equally, ie they both increase. How do I adjust the density so that thicker areas are more affected than the thinner parts in an object?

Comment: Well, the object's thickness with a given density is controlling how thick it looks. A fixed density's will be depending on the thickness as to how thick it looks. If you want the visible density to be different on different parts of the mesh, you have to change the density for certain parts of the mesh with some gradient or texture. I don't know how it should work any other way. But maybe there's someone who got a better idea.

Comment: I understand, but shouldnt it be possible using math and certain input nodes to control the density exponentially? I tried using different setups but so far none worked.

Comment: Yes and no. If you have the density controlled by a noise texture for example with a value x between 0 and 1, using a math node to create an exponential gradient with x^2 is possible. But this way you have an exponential which you can input somewhere for the density. However, the mesh has no "thickness output" giving out a value which you could then calculate with some formula and an input back into the mesh to tell the density, the thickness should be x^2 instead of x.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Gordon. Regarding "thickness output" I would assume that since higher density settings affect thicker parts more than thinner parts (as seen from the viewer's angle) when using volume absorption, Blender knows something about this, hence my question if this information can somehow be used to amplify the behaviour of the volume absorption. I've seen node setups that use Ray length in combination with Backfacing to generate fake absorption, so I was trying to use a similar equation to affect the density, but no luck. Anyway thanks for the texture node solution ;)

Comment: No, it's not higher density settings affecting thicker parts more than thinner parts. The density is (relatively) the same everywhere determined by the value you entered, like if it was e.g. dust, let's say density = 1 means 1000 particles per cubic milimeter. This value is always the same in a homogenous volume. It's the thickness affecting the amount of particles the light has to pass through, not the amount of particles affecting the thickness. And the mesh itself has no "thickness output" which you can plug in the volumetric material and manipulate somehow.